# How to check the input is in date format or intger format? Using java

Tags: java

I have requirement that the user can able to enter either of his datebirth nor age.How could I able to check in my validate method, the entered input is the format of date(dateformate) or age(integerformate).Both I am retrieving in the String format while user entering.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to approach this:

You could for the users to input dates in only one form, and reject other forms via exceptions or another kind of checking. This is probably the shortest option.

You could also use regular expressions or a class like [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to parse the input and handle it. This will allow you to use multiple date formats, but may take a long line of conditionals if you intend to support M/D/Y, D/M/Y, Y/M/D, etc.

Comment: I have written the date Util class already, to parse any format of date. I want to check just input is the date format or not.It might be other format also no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse input with `Integer.parseInt`. If it throws `NumberFormatException` then try to parse input with `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression for the date format you require and use regex.isMatch method to validate the string. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it.

you can first find the length of the input and determine whether the input is date or age then

if it is age you can proceed by checking the input is only numbers

else

you can use regular expression or string tokenizer to split the elements in the date and validate each element or use some format class